# Debug Console in visual studio for ionic app is showing outputoutputoutputoutput

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Recently I am having problem with the console output when debugging ionic app on device.
Messages from browser works fine but not when I am debugging the ionic app on a android device using cordova.

Here is the output from the console, where outputoutput... should be some real logs.

`LAUNCH SUCCESS
No scripts found for hook "after_run".
App successfully launched
Attaching to android
Forwarding debug port
Attaching to app.
outputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutput
outputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutput
outputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutputoutput`

`ordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed`

Answer (score 0):

After I reinstalled the visual studio code, it is now working fine. This is probably caused by newest cordova-plugin (1.2.7) only works with newest visual studio code.